# Numpy IF ELSE construct index error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
x=np.array([(1,2,3),(4,2,6)])
z=np.zeros((2,3))

for i in range(0,x.shape[0]+1):
    print(i)
    if x[i,0] > 1:
        z[i,0]=100
    else:
        z[i,0]=200
    if x[i,1] > 1:
        z[i,1]=100
    else:
        z[i,1]=200
    if x[i,2] > 3:
        z[i,2]=100
    else:
        z[i,2]=200
```

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2.

Cant understand why i am having this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: indexing is zero based so it's out of bounds, also you're iterating over the rows so the row shape[0] will return 2 in this case, you're adding 1 to this which is incorrect also

Answer (score 0):

This is correct as indices will be 0 and 1:

```
for i in range(0,x.shape[0]):
```